# How to remove a reoccuring word/character and what comes after, from the filenames of multiple files?

Tags: macos, file-rename, renaming

I have several folders of video files where, due to the download manager I use, they are all named in the following format "FILENAME.mp4; filename= FILENAME.mp4" All I've been trying to do is to remove everything after (and including) ".mp4; filename". However, I haven't found a way to do this.

I have tried some free software (such as Renamer, Namechanger, Name Munger for Mac, Transnomino) but I failed to do what I need to.

I'm working on Mac OSX 10.13.6.

Any help with this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it using Terminal. Go to the folder where you want to rename files using this `cd` command, for example:

```sh
cd ~/Documents/Videos
```

And run this command to rename all files recursively:

```sh
find . -iname "*.mp4;*" | sed -E 's/(\.[^\.]*)(\.mp4)(.*)/mv "\1\2\3" "\1\2"/' | sh
```

This command will keep only `FILENAME.mp4` part from `FILENAME.mp4; filename= FILENAME.mp4` file name

Comment: Many many thanks for the code, Saik0s. Can I trouble you with a follow up? I think the code may not be working when attempting to rename certain files. I though you might know why this may be (long file names? certain characters appearing in the names?). Here you can see a partial list of the files in that folder after running the code (https://ibb.co/XZq0z4Y). I highlighted the occurrences of "filename" in the file names to show which have been renamed. Also, here is the output when I ran the code on Terminal for this folder (https://ibb.co/LDFQ2Ns). Many many thanks.

Comment: The problem is that the command I wrote was not ready to filenames with dots inside. Here is the improved command 
`find . -iname "*.mp4;*" | perl -pe 's|(.*?)(.mp4;.*)|mv "\1\2" "\1.mp4"|' | sh`

Comment: Wow! Amazing! The new code worked like a charm! :D Thank you so much, Saik0s. Can I ask one last question if you don't mind? Is there anyway to adapt this code to include files which have Arabic characters in their names? I've downloaded thousands of videos for my research and as far as I can tell the code is skipping the files whose names end in Arabic characters. Thank you so much! Argun

Comment: I tried with some Arabic words, and it still works. If you can provide some examples, I can take a look later.

Comment: Thank you so much. Here is another part of the list with occurrences of "filename" highlighted: https://ibb.co/NLjLwFx. And here is the complete file list from the folder if needed: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/1faee3efab5368b1ec82996c2b60406720190611134436/c33167

Comment: Here is updated command: `find . -iname "*filename*" | perl -pe 's|(.*?)(filename=? ?)(.*)|mv "\1\2\3" "\3"|' | sh`

Answer (score 0):

I used to extensively use a windows Rename tool called Renamer 6.0, and it had a "pattern rename" facility called "Multi change" that could have handled this.

In the context of that tool it would be asking for a source pattern like `%a= %b` and a destination pattern (like `%b`), everything after the `=` would be stored in %b variable and then renaming the file to just %b would lose everything after the `=`

See if your preferred rename tool has a similar facility?

If your tool supports regex, then find: `.*?=(.*)` and replace with `$1`

I'm also minded that asking this question on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ might elicit some help crafting a shell script that will perform this rename (though also plenty of shell capable people here, one of them may see it - it's just that it's not quite as hardcore programmer-y a question as most).

If you're willing to learn/use java, then that could be another good way to get the problem solved. It would (at a guess) look something like this:

```
    for (final File f : new File("C:\\temp").listFiles()) {
        if (f.isFile()) {
            string n = f.getName();
            if (n.contains("=")) {
                f.renameTo(new File(n.substring(n.indexOf("=")+1));
            }
        }
    }
```